# notified when a user becomes logged out with an ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

am using ASP.net MVC 5 with Identity 2
Is there a way to be notified when a user becomes logged out with an ASP.net MVC
Note: A user can become logged out without visiting or clicking a "logout" link.
When a user is logged out i want to fetch clear some session related information, and write to a database.
thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Since you know the length of your Authentication cookie, when the user logs in, you can write to Database the date of login and date when it will expire. If, before that, they click logout, update the value with current date and time.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Say that the authentication timeout value is 3 minutes.  This means that after 3 minutes of inactivity, a user will be prompted to login again (note: every time they hit the site the 3 minute window clock gets reset -- so it is only if they are idle that it will timeout).

Comment: If you have a sliding cookie, then logout will happen 3 minutes from last load. Are you logging every page hit for authenticated users? If so, you could go off last activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) without much difficulty. You can create a table for OnlineUsers and Add/Remove within the OnConnected and OnDisconnected events in your hub.

It would be quite hard to achieve a reliable solution without it.

Comment: I believe he means notify the server, not the user, considering he said a user can be logged out without visiting. Which I guess means the cookie expired. Not overly clear.

Comment: yes @MikeSmithDev you are right , i want to log to the database that the user x is log out at y datetime

Comment: Sorry yes I should have been clearer in my explanation. SignalR is a .Net component which allows your server to be aware of the client session in a browser. It uses a combination of web sockets, long polling etc to achieve this. That's all abstracted away from you though. The important thing is that there are 2 events in the SignalR Hub running on the server which you can use to write to the database. Namely, OnConnected/OnReconnected and OnDisconnected.

Comment: thanks @JohnMc but i want to log that the user is logged out (sign out ) he might be still open the web page (still connected) but no longer authenticated

Comment: You have access to the Request object, and can therefore check if the user is Authenticated

Comment: say that the user sign in after that he leave the page opened till he rich the authentication timeout is there an event or something like that fired to tell me that the user is sign out? that's am looking for

Comment: Note: am using the ASP.NET Identity 2 to handle authentication and authorization

Comment: @JohnMc there is no need for SignalR to do this. Either the user logged out because of an action (clicking logout), at which point the server knows he logged out, or he logged out because of inaction (not visiting site before cookie expires), meaning SignalR won't do squat, because the user isn't even connected.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev you're incorrect. Do not confuse a SignalR session with an authentication session as they are not the same thing. A SignalR session will stay alive as long as the page is open. The authentication session will expire due to inactivity.

Comment: @JohnMc I'm not confused about what SignalR does. SignalR isn't going to help when the OP wants to know that the authentication cookie has expired, regardless of whether the user is online or not. He's not talking about Online Users. He is talking about logged-in users. If he were talking about Online Users, then yes SignalR could help. Strange to say I'm incorrect when OP says my description of what he is trying to do it correct.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev totally agree with you ,but kindly what 'OP' means ?

Comment: @teko Original Poster = you